# Android application with two application buttons

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. Currently, I am creating an Android app which should have two launching icons. 
First icon to launch configuration part of the app.
Second icon which will execute based on the configuration.

Configuration will be not be frequent activity.

But launching of second icon will be very frequent to get the results based on configuration.

As I can see most of the apps have single launch icon.
Is there a way in Android which can fit into my requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You can simply add an options menu which will start your 'configuration' `Activity`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application with 2 launcher activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827800/application-with-2-launcher-activities)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two shortcut with Two Icons for the same App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907167/two-shortcut-with-two-icons-for-the-same-app)

Comment: One app two launchers asked and answered many times I think.

Comment: Previous threads helped me in figuring out two launch icons for the same app. Now, I think for my requirement possibly "Widget" could be better option. Goal of my app is, "one time configuration, and frequent one touch execution". Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

In your manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="@string/app_name"android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SettingsActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: After adding android:icon attribute to second activity tag, it worked for me. Thanks!